# Why this simple code with an class which extends EventEmitter give me a NaN result?

Tags: node.js

Probably is a very stupid question but I'm really trying everything and I can't fix this....

I have the following code in node.js  :

Thanks in advance for the help...

```
    const e = require('events');

    class Account extends e {   
        constructor(){
           super();
           this.balance = 0;
           console.log("I'm creating an account with balance %d", this.balance);
    }

    deposit(amount){
        this.balance += amount;
        this.emit("BalanceChanged");
    }

    withdraw(amount) {
        this.balance -= amount;
        this.emit("BalanceChanged");

    }
}

   function displayBalance(acc) {
    console.log("Account Balance : %d",acc.balance);
   }

   function checkOverdraw(acc) {
    if(acc.balance < 0){
        console.log("Account overdrawn !!");
    }
   }

   function checkGoal(acc,goal){
    if (acc.balance > goal)
    {
        concole.log("Goal Achieved !");
    }
   }

   var A = new Account();


   A.on("BalanceChanged",() =>{
    displayBalance(this);
   });
   A.on("BalanceChanged",() => {
    checkOverdraw(this);
   });
   A.on("BalanceChanged", () =>{
    checkGoal(this,1000);
   });

   A.deposit(220);
   A.deposit(320);
   A.deposit(600);
   A.withdraw(1200);
```

The result of the code is  the following :

```
Account Balance : NaN
Account Balance : NaN
Account Balance : NaN
Account Balance : NaN
```

Why NaN ?

It looks like there is a issue in the deposit method but I can't find it....

Any idea ?

Thanks....

@Edit

I tried to change the event handlers according to the following since the this attribute cannot be used in the event handlers :

```
var A = new Account();

A.on("BalanceChanged",() => {
displayBalance(A);});
A.on("BalanceChanged",() => {
checkOverdrawn(A);});
A.on("BalanceChanged",() => {
checkGoal(A);});

A.deposit(220);
A.deposit(320);
A.deposit(600);
A.overdrawn(1200);
```

But I'm still receiving the following output :

```
Account Balance NaN
Account Balance NaN
Account Balance NaN
Account Balance NaN
Account is overdrawn!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is using 'this' inside event handler. Try:

```
A.on("BalanceChanged",() =>{
    console.log(this.balance)
    console.log(this)
    displayBalance(this)
});
```

to see the issue.

In other words, 'this' does not replace A, but rather the global node instance. This will work instead:

```
A.on("BalanceChanged",() =>{
    displayBalance(this.A)
});
```

or simply

```
A.on("BalanceChanged",() =>{
    displayBalance(A)
});
```

Comment: var A = new Account();

A.on("BalanceChanged",() => {
displayBalance(A);});
A.on("BalanceChanged",() => {
checkOverdrawn(A);});
A.on("BalanceChanged",() => {
checkGoal(A);});

A.deposit(220);
A.deposit(320);
A.deposit(600);
A.overdrawn(1200);

Comment: I'm still receiving a NaN value on the output.

Comment: you have some other issues, for example console.log() in one of the functions does not match word console (probably some chars typed in different language). See this: https://repl.it/repls/ForestgreenOutlyingUpgrade